# Argument passed to when() is not a mock! Example of correct stubbing: doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someMethod();

Tags: kotlin, junit, mockito, junit4

When using Mockito in JUnit4, I encounter the error in the title.

My code is shown below

```
package cn.patest.judgerAutoscalerKotlin

import org.junit.Test
import org.mockito.*

import java.lang.RuntimeException

class CalculateScaleToTest {
    @Mock
    private lateinit var test: cn.patest.judgerAutoscalerKotlin.Test

    private fun mockTest() {
        test = cn.patest.judgerAutoscalerKotlin.Test()
        Mockito.doAnswer { 1 }.`when`(test).test()
    }


    @Test
    fun z() {
        mockTest()
    }
}
```

```
package cn.patest.judgerAutoscalerKotlin

class Test() {
    fun test(): Int {
        return 1
    }
}
```

Error details are shown below:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: 
>   Argument passed to when() is not a mock!
>   Example of correct stubbing:
>       doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someMethod();
>     at cn.patest.judgerAutoscalerKotlin.CalculateScaleToTest.mockTest(CalculateScaleToTest.kt:53)
>       at cn.patest.judgerAutoscalerKotlin.CalculateScaleToTest.z(CalculateScaleToTest.kt:61)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)

I searched with google and found some similar issues but they have different situations from mine.

Comment: It will be incredibly easier to use mockk, if you are using kotlin. It saved me days

Comment: I think you are missing the mockito rule: `@Rule public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule(); ` (added as a field to your test class).

Comment: @Arcanefoam I added `    @get:Rule
    var mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule()` as you suggest.  After that, I encounter the same error.

Comment: You sure this is Java? Set appropriate tags please

Answer (score 2):

With:

```java
    test = cn.patest.judgerAutoscalerKotlin.Test()
```

you create a real object, not a mocked one.

Remove the above line and add:

```java
  @Before
  fun before() {

    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks( this )
  }
```

Reference:

- [Mock](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.3.3/org/mockito/Mock.html)
- [MockitoAnnotations](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.3.3/org/mockito/MockitoAnnotations.html)

> **MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)** method has to be called to initialize annotated fields.

Note also that mocking the class under test in a real environment doesn't make any sense (in contrast to a MCVE like here).